# SQL Join Multiple Tables with One to Many Relationships without "Duplication"

Tags: sql, duplicates, one-to-many

First let me start by saying that I do understand that these are not duplicate rows. I understand the basic functionality of joining multiple tables. I am just trying to find out if there is a way to do what I am trying to do in SQL and I don't know a better way to title it.

Example Tables:

```
Day Table
Day_KEY Day_Label
1       Mon
2       Tues
3       Wed
4       Thur

EstHours Table
EstHours_KEY Day_KEY Est_Hours
1            1       2
2            1       1
3            1       3

ActHours Table
ActHours_KEY Day_KEY Act_Hours
1            1       3
2            1       2
3            1       2
```

Example Query:

```
select *
from Day
join EstHours on EstHours.Day_KEY = Day.Day_KEY
join ActHours on ActHours.Day_KEY = Day.Day_KEY
```

Result:

```
Day_KEY Day_Label EstHours_KEY Day_KEY Est_Hours ActHours_KEY Day_KEY Act_Hours
1       Mon       1            1       2         1            1       3
1       Mon       1            1       2         2            1       2
1       Mon       1            1       2         3            1       2
1       Mon       2            1       1         1            1       3
1       Mon       2            1       1         2            1       2
1       Mon       2            1       1         3            1       2
1       Mon       3            1       3         1            1       3
1       Mon       3            1       3         2            1       2
1       Mon       3            1       3         3            1       2
```

Desired Result:

```
Day_KEY Day_Label EstHours_KEY Day_KEY Est_Hours ActHours_KEY Day_KEY Act_Hours
1       Mon       1            1       2         1            1       3
1       Mon       2            1       1         2            1       2
1       Mon       3            1       3         3            1       2
```

What I have tried:

1)
Query:

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by Day.Day_KEY order by EstHours_KEY) as rn
    from Day
    join EstHours on EstHours.Day_KEY = Day.Day_KEY) rt
join (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by Day_KEY order by ActHours_KEY) as rn
    from ActHours) on ActHours.Day_KEY = Day.Day_KEY and EstHours.rn = ActHours.rn
```

Result:

```
Day_KEY Day_Label EstHours_KEY Day_KEY Est_Hours ActHours_KEY Day_KEY Act_Hours
1       Mon       1            1       2         1            1       3
1       Mon       2            1       1         2            1       2
1       Mon       3            1       3         3            1       2
```

This does what I need unless the EstHours has less rows than the ActHours, in which case it will leave those rows out from ActHours.

2)
Query:

```
select *, null, null, null
from Day
join EstHours on EstHours.Day_KEY = Day.Day_KEY

union

select Day.*, null, null, null, ActHours.*
from Day
join ActHours on ActHours.Day_KEY = Day.Day_KEY
```

Result:

```
Day_KEY Day_Label EstHours_KEY Day_KEY Est_Hours ActHours_KEY Day_KEY Act_Hours
1       Mon       1            1       2         null         null    null
1       Mon       2            1       1         null         null    null
1       Mon       3            1       3         null         null    null
1       Mon       null         null    null      1            1       3
1       Mon       null         null    null      2            1       2
1       Mon       null         null    null      3            1       2
```

This does what I want except I would prefer the values to be on the same rows, so that the maximum number of rows for a single Day_KEY would be that of the either the EstHours or ActHours, whichever has more.

Has anyone any idea of how this can be done? Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Please provide table structures, Sample data and expected output.

Comment: I have updated most all of it with visual examples now.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a 'group by' clause that has a unique/distinct field belonging to the 'one' table in the one to many relationship. Such as a row id.

```
select * from table_a,table_b,table_c group by table_a.rowid
```

This will collapse the results to distinct rows from table_a, and also allow the select result to use/include aggregate functions like sum() on the fields from table_b or table_c.
In the example I used, think of every row from table_b and table_c overlapping with the unique rows of table_a that get returned.

Comment: I see where you are going with this but I was hoping to get the rows of values piped into my reporting software and aggregating it through that software instead of aggregating it within SQL and piping in only the aggregations.